# NodeJS - MS Azure IoT

Tags: node.js, cloud, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-suite

I was doing a bit of research on Azure IoT Hub and was pleasantly surprised to see that it doesn't have the SDK for Objective C.

How do you propose we get around this?

One option could be :

1) Create our own Web Server using NodeJS.

2) Use Azure IoT NodeJS SDK to connect our web server with Azure IoT.

3) We will then create web services (APIs) to connect the phone (Android, iOS) with the web server, which in turn connects to Azure IoT ?

So the over all process would be something like this :

> • User wants to see his profile ( assume that the profile is stored in
>   one of the tables in SQLAzure ).
>
> • He taps on the "Profile" Button.
>
> • API (most probably REST API) call is made from Mobile to web server
>   on "Profile" Button tap.
>
> • Our web server will then talk to Azure and do the necessary fetching
>   and return the data to the mobile in JSON format.
>
> • We will then parse this information at our end and display it to the
>   user.

We are hoping to achieve independence from end users phone operating system using the above scenario. This will also help us make our app lightweight and provided we are not adding Azure SDK's to our app bundle, but rather accessing them over the web servers.

Hope its the right way to go about it. If theres an better way to do the same thing please do let me know.

Looking forward to hear from you.

I have been advised to use Azure Mobile Services SDK but I am afraid that it would not allow me to take leverage of commands present in Azure IoT Hub SDKs.

Then again I maybe wrong altogether maybe I don't need to call IoT directly on my mobile. Maybe I just need to my mobile to show the pushed and pulled data from Azure.

Any Azure Experts?? HELP!!!

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you considering mixing Objective-C code with the azure IoT SDK for C? You may end up creating some simple Objective-C wrapper classes around c, and with the minimum efforts, expose only the necessary APIs you may need.

Comment: All said and done thats exactly what I needed to do. Sorry for late acceptance